# CSS: Possible to select a certain child plus the immediate following sibling?

Tags: css, css-selectors, siblings

I'm currently doing this using Javascript, however, I was wondering if it's possible to select a certain child of an unordered-list and then its immediate sibling, using CSS.

Example with 4 list-items:

```
ul.tab li:hover + (the next sibling that follows the current hovered one) {

}
```

Comment: CSS3 allows this, but the description on the standard is inadequate, favorited...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [adjacent sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector) for which you amusingly basically have the syntax already.

Be advised: `:hover` is specifically a x-browser problem in Safari though.

Comment: Bah, I didn't even bother trying my guess hehe...so close! Thanks much annakata!

Comment: Is there a more controlled way to get a sibling? As in: `A-P{}` to get the last sibling or `A+3P{}` to get the 3rd sibling?

Comment: @J-V: there's the general sibling selector `~` (http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector) which doesn't care about the reference being an immediate previous sibling, but still must be a previous sibling. What you're describing is not directly achievable but should be possible with the CSS3 nth-child selectors and similar (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos).